# Check row exist or not in Ruby on Rails

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and I have basic knowledge of mysql. I am using MySQL db. My question is -- how to check if a row is exists or not in a table. I have tried this code but it's not going straight to the `else` block, not the `if` block:

```
@tasks = User.find_by("user_name = ? AND password = ?", params[:user_name], params[:password])
if @tasks
  redirect_to action: 'index', status: 302
else
  redirect_to action: 'detail', status: 302
end
```

Comment: In the future, if something doesn't work as expected, please explain ***in what way*** that it's not working, like if you're getting any error messages, or what the response is, even if it's not the right one.

Comment: Try to find the users with unique fields.

Comment: #cupcake--I am not getting any error msg. It is going directly into else condition

Comment: @Bharatsoni .. I did't get u

Comment: Which field you have unique in your users table ?

Comment: I have only one row in table .. id, user_name, password

Comment: `User.find_by_user_name_and_password(params[:user_name], params[:password])` This will work. But use `where` as suggested by @Cupcake.

Comment: @D'Scolz what version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails are you using?

Comment: Try running your find_by statement in ruby console and check if there are any errors.

Comment: ya. got it. @Cupcake edited my question. Now it is working properly.

Comment: @D'Scolz what do you mean? What was the other solution?

Comment: `@tasks = User.find_by("user_name = ? AND password = ?", params[:user_name], params[:password])`

Comment: @Cupcake .. your edited answer is working properly

Comment: @Cupcake OP meant the removal of string interpolation in the `find_by`

Comment: @D'Scolz by the way, it's a convention in Ruby to use 2-space indent, not 4-space.

Comment: @Cupcake.. thank you. I am updating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to find if a user with the given name and password exists using Ruby on Rails, then you can do this:

```
User.where(user_name: params[:user_name], password: params[:password]).exists?
```

See the [RailsGuides: Existence of Objects](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#existence-of-objects).

#### The Cause of the Original Problem?

So this it the code that the original poster originally submitted:

```
User.find_by("user_name = ? AND password = ?", "#{params[:user_name]}", "#{params[:password]}")
```

I removed the string interpolation because it was unnecessary

```
User.find_by("user_name = ? AND password = ?", params[:user_name], params[:password])
```

and [apparently that fixed the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928038/check-row-exist-or-not-in-ruby-on-rails?noredirect=1#comment35000171_22928038). I'm not sure why it would make a difference though, the interpolated string should be the same value as the values in the `params` dictionary.

Comment: thanks it is working.. But whatever i have written is it wrong?

Comment: @D'Scolz I can't actually tell, what you had originally looks like it should work too.

Comment: @D'Scolz there is no `find_by` in rails.

Comment: @akshay actually, [there is](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by).

Comment: @Cupcake please help me on [Twitter-bootstrap-rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22939854/twitter-bootstrap-in-ruby-on-rails)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any of these solutions depending on your requirement.

**Sol-1:**

```
User.where(user_name: params[:user_name], password: params[:password]).exists?
```

**Sol-2:**

```
User.find_by_user_name_and_password(params[:user_name], params[:password])
```

- [`where`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where) returns an [`ActiveRecord::Relation`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) (not an array, even though it behaves much like one), which is a *collection* of model objects. If nothing matches the conditions, it simply returns an empty relation.
- [`find`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) (and its related dynamic `find_by_columnname` methods) returns a *single* model object, or possibly a collection of model objects in an Array (not a Relation). If nothing is found, an [`ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/RecordNotFound.html) exception is raised.

So yes, if you only want and expect a single object, using `find` is easier, as otherwise you must call `Model.where.first`.

Comment: that means ... suppose i have 2 rows in table and both row have same data. in this case if i use **where** then i will get both the values

Comment: Accept one of the answers which you felt helped you most. That would help other users.

Answer (score 1):

you can try it as well..

`User.find_by_user_name_and_password(params[:user_name], params[:password])`