# Twitter Bootstrap in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I want to integrate twitter-boostrap in my Ruby on Rails project.
For that i have written- `gem "therubyracer"` `gem "less-rails"`  `gem "twitter-bootstrap-rails"` on my gemfile. And then `bundle install` in *rails command prompt*. 
After installing `less-rails`. This error is comming

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR:
Failed to build gem native extension` 
c:/row/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb`
creating Makefile
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.`
c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:58:
in `setup_python!': libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build, b
ut it is currently not available (RuntimeError)
from c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:42:in `block in build_libv8!'
from c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `chdir'
from c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/builder.rb:40:in `build_libv8!'
from c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/location.rb:24:in `install!'
from extconf.rb:7:in `<main>'

Gem files will remain installed in c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8 -3.16.14.3 for inspection.
Results logged to c:/row/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/libv8-3.16.14.3/ext/libv8/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing libv8 (3.16.14.3), and Bundler cannotcontinue.
Make sure that `gem install libv8 -v '3.16.14.3'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Help. thanks

Comment: I'm curious how this: `libv8 requires python 2 to be installed in order to build` does not make it obvious what is wrong with your install.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
group :assets do 
end
```

But keep gems mentioned inside this group, then do bundle install.

```
gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'devise'
```

Comment: After `Using less-rails (2.5.0)` the error is coming

Comment: @D'Scolz Try this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19673714/rails-gem-install-error-error-installing-libv8-error-failed-to-build-gem-nati

Comment: I have tried that. but not getting positive response.. Showing same error